# How can add a click listener to label of a chart with anychart and vue.js?

Tags: json, anychart

I am writing a Vue.js application for showing a radar chart using Anychart.js Library.
My current problem is adding a click listener to labels of radar chart.
Using plain js I can use this istruction:

```
chart
    .xAxis()
    .labels()
    .listen("click", function (e) {
      // get the index of the hovered labels, 0 based
      var labelIndex = e.labelIndex;
      //do something with labelIndex
    });
```

How can I achieve the same result using the json notation?

I am trying with this:

```
  chart: {
...
          xAxis: {
            labels: {
              enabled: true,
              width: "48px",
              height: "48px",
              format: function () {},
              background: {
                enabled: true,
                fill: {
                  src: myImg_path,
                  mode: "fit",
                },
              },
              listen: {
                type: "click",
                listener: function () {
                  alert("hello");
                },
              },
            },
          },
...
}
```

but when I click the labels nothing happens.
I am not sure if the *listen* property is correct and I cannot find anything in anychart site about this signature.
How can I solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To make a click event you must follow the following structure

```
chart.listen("rowClick", function (e) {
  var itemName = e.item.get("name");
  chart.title("Events: Chart<br><br>" +
              "< <span style = 'color:#990000'>" +
              itemName + "</span>: rowClick >");
});
```

**Oficial Documentation**

https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Events

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,
I just wrote to anychart support and they told me that utilizing listen() method is possible only with JS configuration.
However, it is possible to apply the listeners after parsing JSON.
I will follow this way then.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Is it possible for you share the support's response link (if available)

Comment: This is the response they sent me:

Hello Alessandro!

Utilizing listen() method is possible only with JS configuration.
However, it is possible to apply the listeners after parsing JSON.

Please, explore the Playground Demo we have prepared for you.
https://playground.anychart.com/gTVhmslG

Let us know if you have any additional questions!